# VB.net Regular expression to return until last sentence before ellipsis or three full-stops

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am trying to write an expression to take a block of text an return up until a full-stop before an ellipsis or three full-stops (`...` or `…`). So the idea is that  the example text test string:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam felis nisi, eleifend ut quam eget, venenatis vestibulum turpis. Nam dignissim laoreet iaculis. Etiam sit amet rhoncus sem. Duis laoreet justo tellus, at volutpat risus molestie sed. Etiam posuere, arcu vitae faucibus hendrerit, lorem elit consequat urna, id congue eros felis in mauris. Donec non fermentum ipsum. Curabitur nec...`

Would become:

`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam felis nisi, eleifend ut quam eget, venenatis vestibulum turpis. Nam dignissim laoreet iaculis. Etiam sit amet rhoncus sem. Duis laoreet justo tellus, at volutpat risus molestie sed. Etiam posuere, arcu vitae faucibus hendrerit, lorem elit consequat urna, id congue eros felis in mauris. Donec non fermentum ipsum.`

So far I have come up with this pathetic attempt. I keep getting right up until the last full-stop (because the quantifier consumes the previous two full-stops so there is nothing for the look ahead to fail on). I just can't seem to wrap my head around it:

```
    Dim testText As String = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam felis nisi, eleifend ut quam eget, venenatis vestibulum turpis. Nam dignissim laoreet iaculis. Etiam sit amet rhoncus sem. Duis laoreet justo tellus, at volutpat risus molestie sed. Etiam posuere, arcu vitae faucibus hendrerit, lorem elit consequat urna, id congue eros felis in mauris. Donec non fermentum ipsum. Curabitur nec..."
    Dim ellipsisExpression As String = "(.*\.(?!\.\.))"
    Dim ellipsisMatch As Match
    ellipsisMatch = Regex.Match(testText, ellipsisExpression)
    If ellipsisMatch.Success Then
        testText = ellipsisMatch.Groups(1).Value
    End If
```

edit: I also need this expression to take any `...` character in the text into account. for example the string:

```
`begin. this is a test... test complete. beginning shutdown... shutting down... `
```

should return

```
`begin. this is a test... test complete.`
```

The aim of this expression is to find the most flowing text before any truncation has occurred. A block of text with closure so it doesn't confuse readers expecting to be able to 'get more'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have come up with a solution that works for me. Thank you to everyone who answered previously but this expression seems to do what I need and doesn't execute as slowly as some of the other answers. It also takes other sentence terminating punctuation into account such as `!` or `?` and not just `.`.

```
(.*([^\.](?=\.|\?|!)(?!\.\.\.)).)
```

This get's the last sentence terminating character (defined with the lookahead). In this case they are `?`, `!` and `.` that isn't followed by `...`. This also solves the ellipsis character issue since it is effectively a sentence terminating white list. This expression succeeds in finding the largest block of text with closure.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `[^.]*(?:\.{3}|…).*` with an empty string to get the desired result.

For example:

```
result = Regex.Replace(input, "[^.]*(?:\\.{3}|…).*", "")
```

Comment: I see what you mean. But what about the case where there are two ellipsis characters like: `this is a test. testing... testing...`, your provided expression would only replace the last ellipsis block.

Comment: @JonM, that wasn't in the example. What is the desired result of that? If you just want to remove those, drop the `$` in the expression above, like `[^.]*(?:\.{3}|…)`.

Comment: "I am trying to write an expression to take a block of text an return up until a full-stop before an ellipsis or three full-stops"

Comment: @JonM, replacing `[^.]*(?:\.{3}|…).*` with empty string should work then.

Comment: ahhh I see, unfortunately this won't work for blocks of text that have "..." in them but haven't terminated yet. I need this expression to find the last full-stop that isnt an ellipsis before the last ellipsis. I'll update my question

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
result = Regex.Replace(input, "(.+\.).+(?:\.{3}|…)\s*", "$1")
```

**Edit:**

Use this regex instead:

```
(.+[^.]\.)(?:(?:[^.]{2})|$)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer `"(.+\.).+(?:\.{3}|…)\s*"` but what about a situation where there is more than one ellipsis terminated sentence? This won't work on the text for example `this is a test. testing... testing...` as it will return `this is a test. testing...`

Answer (score 0):

You could match that with:

```
.*(?<!\.)\.(?!\.)(?=(?:[^.]+|\.{3})*(?:\.{3}|…)$)
```

Or replace

```
(?<!\.)\.(?!\.)(?:[^.]+|\.{3})*(?:\.{3}|…)$
```

with a `.`.

Comment: `(?<!\.)\.(?!\.)(?:[^.]+|\.{3})*(?:\.{3}|…)$` This expression seems to suffer quite heavily from backtracking, while not catastrophic it is very slow. I thank you for spending your time on this but I think I have come up with a solution myself which, while i didn't specify it, allows other sentence terminating characters to be taken into account...